# Как манипулировать событиями jquery?

Tags: jquery, события

Есть кнопка, по клику на которую открывается форма и фокус ставится в `input`. При потере фокуса - форма скрывается. Также если есть фокус и кликнуть еще раз по кнопку, то форма тоже должна скрыться.

Но при скрытии формы, все равно обрабатывается `blur` и `click` дублируется.

Вопрос: как избежать такой ситуации?
Пробовала навешивать `click` триггеров, все равно тоже самое. 
Также пыталась получить события текущие, но ничего не вышло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Вот ссылка на пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYGdjZ

Спасибо!

Comment: Кликнуть по кнопке `Отправить` у вас тоже не получится. Вам нужно с другой стороны подходить к вопросу. Не отслеживать бесконечные `blur` и `focus`, а, например, отслеживать клик ВНЕ `form`

Comment: Спасибо, переделала, благодарю ) Все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решить данную проблему можно используя [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) и [jQuery.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) которые позволяют добавлять и удалять события. Просто перед скрытии формы требуется удалить все события и добавить их при показе ее.

Comment: Спасибо! использовала `.off` и `.on` и клик вне формы.